# Windows 10 automatically unmounts virtual drive on MS Surface

Tags: windows-10, mount, microsoft-surface

I'm using dokan to create a user mode file system and mount this to a NTFS volume mount point. On Surface Books I noticed, that this file system frequently gets unmounted when the display is put to sleep. This does not seem to happen on other notebooks, even after days of hibernation. Does anyone know if there is something special regarding mounted file systems on Windows 10 on Surface Books? If so, can this be influenced somehow?

EDIT:

As @Ramhound pointed out, it is probably related to the power mode. So maybe the question should rather be: Is there some power scheme/mode in which devices get unmounted, which might be present on Surface Books but not on other Notebooks?

Comment: What exactly is Dokan.  How are you mounting it exactly l. Provide specifics.  This problem isn’t related to the hardware (besides the possibility it’s connected to the power state itself)

Comment: Dokan is a user mode file system that in a nutshell consists of a kernel mode driver that forwards file system operations to a user mode app. It provides an own api for mounting, as described here https://dokan-dev.github.io/dokany-doc/html/group___dokan.html#ga099fb73df80893f9da337a2dd7a6634e so I'm afraid I cannot provide much details on the internals

Comment: Sleep mode != Hibernation mode two entirely different power modes

Comment: Ok, but the app is run on many Windows Notebooks and this issue only ever happens on Surface books. I can put my Windows to sleep (Start -> Power -> Sleep) and nothing gets unmounted.

Comment: Again.  If you are putting other hardware to Sleep, that’s is an entirely different power state, then when you put your Surface Book into hibernation.

Comment: Can i use `powercfg` to set my Windows into the same power state as a surface with display off for testing?